# android FunctionCallback get data

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to use "callFunctionInBackground" the problem is that I can't get the data from it.
I tried with another class, but the callFunctionInBackground is executed after the r.recivedResult.get("startingText").

what can I do to get the data ?

```
    resultsClass r = new resultsClass();
    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(funcName, h , r);
    String s = (String)r.recivedResult.get("startingText");

 public class resultsClass extends FunctionCallback<Object>{
    public HashMap<String , Object> recivedResult = new HashMap<String , Object>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void done(Object result, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {

            recivedResult = ((HashMap<String, Object>)result);
            recivedResult.put("Titles" , ((ArrayList<String>)recivedResult.get("buttonTitles")));
            recivedResult.put("startingText" , (String)recivedResult.get("textPrefix"));
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`callFunctionInBackground` calls your `resultsClass` at some later time, after it received the data from parsecloud.

So you will need a way to execute the statement `r.recivedResult.get` after the data is returned successfully.

try [using a handler](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) -

- replace

  ```
  ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(funcName, h , r);
  String s = (String)r.recivedResult.get("startingText");
  ```

  with

  ```
  Handler dataReceivedHandler = new Handler() {
      public void handleMessage(Message m) {
          if (m.what == 0) {
              String s = (String)r.recivedResult.get("startingText");
              // use the string s in your activity            
          }
  };
  r.dataReceivedHandler = dataReceivedHandler;
  ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground(funcName, h , r);
  ```
- and add this line at the end of your `done` function in `resultsClass`;

  ```
  dataReceivedHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  ```

  and declare a pulbic member `dataReceivedHandler` in your `resultsClass`, or use a setter/getter

  ```
  public Handler dataReceivedHandler;
  ```